# Animate changing LayoutParams (RelativeLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

when I click on a RelativeLayout it change the size.
How can I make this change animated? So it looks like the rectangle grows to full screen?

My Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ff000000">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/srLayout"
    android:layout_width="62.5dp"
    android:layout_height="132.5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="sleepRoom"
    android:background="#ffffffff"></RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code:

```
public void sleepRoom(View view) {
    RelativeLayout sr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(view.getId());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) sr.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    sr.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To explicitly animate in this case, your `sleepRoom()` should look like this.

```
public void sleepRoom(View view) {
    final RelativeLayout sr = (RelativeLayout) view;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) sr.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    sr.setLayoutParams(params);

    PropertyValuesHolder pvhLeft = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("left", 0, 1);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhTop = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("top", 0, 1);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhRight = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("right", 0, 1);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhBottom = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("bottom", 0, 1);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhRoundness = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("roundness", 0, 1);


    final Animator collapseExpandAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(sr, pvhLeft, pvhTop,
            pvhRight, pvhBottom, pvhRoundness);
    collapseExpandAnim.setupStartValues();

    sr.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            sr.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            collapseExpandAnim.setupEndValues();
            collapseExpandAnim.start();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

However, normally `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` should work.

For more specifics from the man Chet Haase, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g

Comment: I added `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` but doesn't work for my example

Comment: Updated answer, try it. ;)

Comment: Is this only for expanding? How to colapse? Thx.

Comment: No, you would need to animate then change your LayoutParams; since you cannot draw outside of your bounds pre-Lollipop. Because if you shrink your layout before you animate the animation would be clipped.

Answer (score 28):

Simple trick that worked for me:

Adding:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

to the xml of the view whose layoutParams you are changing.

Then, adding this line of code in your Java/Kotlin code before changing the params:

Java:

```
((ViewGroup) sr).getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

Kotlin:

```
(sr as ViewGroup).layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
```

Answer (score 1):

because `RelativeLayout` extends `View` you can use all the animations you are using on *"regular views"*. for example try using [animate.scale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate()) and see if it suits you. a simple way of doing it will be something like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   sr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(view.getId());
   sv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   scaleEnd = sr.getScaleX();
   sr.setScaleX(0);
}

...
@Override
protected void onPostCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sr.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    sr.animate.scaleX(scaleEnd);
}
```

Also if you want a `Lollipop` kind of animation have a look at: [Use the Reveal Effect](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html)