# RecyclerView expand/collapse too fast

Tags: android, android-animation

My RecyclerView contains items of various types. One of the types has a TextView title and a RecyclerView for showing a list. A click on the title will populate/unpopulate the RecyclerView thus expanding/collapsing it.

I think I notice an expand/collapse animation but it's very fast. The question is how to slow it down so it's more noticeable?

The code:

```
...
itemView.showIncludedCountriesTextAndArrowLayout.setOnClickListener {

    val whatCountriesAreIncludedLayout: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.whatCountriesAreIncludedLayout)

    if (countryGridAdapter?.itemCount == 0) {
        itemView.upOrDownArrowImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_up_arrow_32dp)
        itemView.showTheIncludedCountriesTextView.text = mobileSubscriptionSiteCoreSectionData.countriesListCollapseText

        countryGridAdapter.updateList(mobileSubscriptionSiteCoreSectionData.countryList)

        // Bottom margin.
        val layoutParams = whatCountriesAreIncludedLayout.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.countriesIncludedVisibleList)
        whatCountriesAreIncludedLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams

        recyclerView.requestLayout()
        recyclerView.invalidate()

        onShowHideListViewClickListener.onClick(it, true, viewHolder.adapterPosition,
                (itemView.showIncludedCountriesTextAndArrowLayout.top +
                        itemView.showIncludedCountriesTextAndArrowLayout.paddingTop +
                        itemView.showIncludedCountriesTextAndArrowLayout.paddingBottom) * -1)

    } else {
        itemView.upOrDownArrowImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_down_arrow_32dp)
        itemView.showTheIncludedCountriesTextView.text = mobileSubscriptionSiteCoreSectionData.countriesListExpandText

        countryGridAdapter?.updateList(listOf())

        // Bottom margin.
        val layoutParams = whatCountriesAreIncludedLayout.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0
        whatCountriesAreIncludedLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams

        recyclerView.requestLayout()
        recyclerView.invalidate()

        onShowHideListViewClickListener.onClick(it, false)
    }
}
...
```

[Here is a short video of the current behavior](https://photos.app.goo.gl/21ZRTpikSvBu6tEj7)

Comment: Use ObjectAnimator to animate changes in layout params.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29900446/4042468

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I used the following post from your link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159490/1545435

Answer (score 0):

Add
`android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

in your itemviewlayout. A default animation will be displayed with a small duration